# XPath to get attributes containing a specific value, regardless of name

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML that contains elements like this

```
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:SplitViewAutoBehavior ToggleAction="{Binding NavBar.ToggleAction, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                     CollapseOnClickAction="{Binding NavBar.CollapseOnClickAction, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                     CollapseThreshold="{StaticResource SplitViewCollapseThreshold}" />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I would like to scan the whole XML structure for attributes whose values start with `"{Binding"`, regardless of the name of the attribute.

I have tried so far with several syntax variations, but I haven't found a syntax when the attribute name you look for is unknown, and you look for values instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//@*[starts-with(.,'{Binding')]
```

will select all attributes whose values start with `'{Binding'`, as requested.